# Elimination of Arbitrary Constant in the equation $y= c-\frac{\ln x}{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I found this question while helping somebody and I tried to solve it myself. It goes like this:

> How to eliminate the constant in the equation $y = c - \frac{\ln x}{x}?$

My work:

I have almost no experience regarding arbitrary constant elimination.....but it seems is a differential equation topic.

I've seen few examples of these in the Internet so I applied what I learned to the equation above.

To eliminate the constant of the equation above:

$$y = c - \frac{\ln x}{x}$$

Implicitly differentiating the above equation:

$$y' = 0 - d \left (\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)$$
$$y' = 0- \left( \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}\right)$$
$$y' =   \frac{-1+\ln x}{x^2}$$
$$x^2 y' = -1 + \ln x$$

Ultimately, I got a differential equation $x^2 y' = -1 + \ln x.$ I just want to make sure that I'm doing it right. Is my solution correct?

Comment: i think your equation is right

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Oh I see.....thanks for the opinion!:-D